# Solr 7 not removing a node completely due to too small thread pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, exception, solr, autoscaling

## Situation

I'm currently trying to set up SolrCloud in an AWS Autoscaling Group, so that it can scale dynamically.

I've also added the following triggers to Solr, so that each node will have 1 (and only one) replication of each collection:

```
{
"set-cluster-policy": [
  {"replica": "<2", "shard": "#EACH", "node": "#EACH"}
  ],
  "set-trigger": [{
    "name": "node_added_trigger",
    "event": "nodeAdded",
    "waitFor": "5s",
    "preferredOperation": "ADDREPLICA"
  },{
    "name": "node_lost_trigger",
    "event": "nodeLost",
    "waitFor": "120s",
    "preferredOperation": "DELETENODE"
  }]
}
```

This works pretty well. But my problem is that when the a node gets removed, it doesn't remove all 19 replicas from this node and I have problems when accessing the "nodes" page:

[image]

In the logs, this exception occurs:

```
Operation deletenode failed:java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor$$Lambda$45/1104948431@467049e2 rejected from org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor@773563df[Running, pool size = 10, active threads = 10, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2063)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:830)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1379)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ExecutorUtil.java:194)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.api.collections.DeleteReplicaCmd.deleteCore(DeleteReplicaCmd.java:276)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.api.collections.DeleteReplicaCmd.deleteReplica(DeleteReplicaCmd.java:95)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.api.collections.DeleteNodeCmd.cleanupReplicas(DeleteNodeCmd.java:109)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.api.collections.DeleteNodeCmd.call(DeleteNodeCmd.java:62)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.api.collections.OverseerCollectionMessageHandler.processMessage(OverseerCollectionMessageHandler.java:292)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.OverseerTaskProcessor$Runner.run(OverseerTaskProcessor.java:496)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:209)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

## Problem description

So, the problem is that it only has a pool size of 10, of which 10 are busy and nothing gets queued (synchronous execution). In fact, it really only removed 10 replicas and the other 9 replicas stayed there. When manually sending the API command to delete this node it works fine, since Solr only needs to remove the remaining 9 replicas and everything is good again.

## Question

How can I either increase this (small) thread pool size and/or activate queueing the remaining deletion tasks? Another solution might be to retry the failed task until it succeeds.

Using Solr 7.7.1 on Ubuntu Server installed with the installation script from Solr (so I guess it's using Jetty?).

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT:** I got feedback from the Solr user group mailing list. This seems to be a design flaw: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-11208
Doesn't seem to be configurable right now, but if anyone having a workaround ready, I'd be happy to learn it.

Comment: I suggest asking this on the solr-user mailing list and updating the question with the answer you get there - more limited solr cloud stuff usually need a larger audience than on Stack Overflow to get a quick answer.

Comment: Thanks, I did it and will update my question if I receive feedback there.